# Visual Studio 2013 debug Android

Tags: visual-studio-2013, onsen-ui, monaca

I downloaded Apache Cordova CTP3.0 for VS2013.

If I create a new Cordova project I notice I have the option to debug using Android in the configuration manager.

I have a Monaca project that I previously created but that only lists "Any CPU". How do you add Android to the configuration manager so I can debug in Android?

Answer (score 0):

To develop Monaca project on Visual Studio, you should install the following extension (called Monaca for Visual Studio).

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1ed1f1bd-494e-45da-99ac-6e05b2648eef

Then you could start running the app on Monaca Debugger.

Comment: Is it possible to take advantage of the Android emulator or Ripple that come with Visual Studio 2013 - Apache Cordova or is the only way to do it with Monaca Debugger?

Comment: Currently Monaca Debugger is the only supported option.